# How to execute a function in Jupyter that was defined in a different cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I defined a function in a Jupyter Lab cell and is working fine but if I try to execute the same function on a different cell I've got the error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'count_persistence_fail'**. How can I execute a function on different cells? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just need to execute the cell where function defined. That should put it in runtime and it will be accessible in other cells right after.

Answer (score 2):

first execute the cell where the function was defined and then execute the calling cell

check [This for more information](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Running%20Code.html)

Answer (score 0):

just do this `>>> function name`

Comment: The original question was for running code in a Jupyter Notebook, while `>>>` indicates running it in a Python interpreter. And, `function name` will not execute the function, for both Jupyter Notebook and on the interpreter.